# Java mail works using gmail as host but not godaddy

Tags: java

I am currently working on forgot password feature and I am using javax.mail. I tried `smtp.gmail.com` as my host and it worked fine in local and live server. The link below, you can see there's a `mailed-by and signed-by gmail`.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evzRp.png)

However, using `smtpout.secureserver.net` will only work in local server.

In live server, it says `Could not connect to SMTP host: smtpout.secureserver.net, port: 465, response: 554`. And, I don't see `signed-by and mailed-by` when viewing the email even in local server.

Do I really need to buy a certificate from GoDaddy to see`signed-by and mailed-by`? Also, could this be the reason why it won't work in live server? I am sorry I'm really new to this.

Here's the code:

```
public class Mailer {
    Message message;
    Transport transport;
    Properties props;

    private String userName = "my@email.com";
    private String passWord = "password@123";
    private String protocol = "smtp";
    private String host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    private String port = "465";
    private String socketFactoryClass = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";


    private final String
        MAIL_SMTP_START_TLS_ENABLE          =           "mail.smtp.starttls.enable",
        MAIL_SMTP_AUTH                      =           "mail.smtp.auth",
        MAIL_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL             =           "mail.transport.protocol",
        MAIL_DEBUG                          =           "mail.debug",
        MAIL_SMTP_PORT                      =           "mail.smtp.port",
        MAIL_SMTP_HOST                      =           "mail.smtp.host",
        MAIL_SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_PORT        =           "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",
        MAIL_SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_CLASS       =           "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
        MAIL_SMTP_SSL_ENABLE                =           "mail.smtp.ssl.enable";

 public Mailer() {
        setProperties();
    }

    public void setProperties() {
        props = System.getProperties();
        props.put(MAIL_SMTP_AUTH, true);
//      props.put(MAIL_SMTP_START_TLS_ENABLE, true);
        props.put(MAIL_DEBUG, true);
        props.put(MAIL_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL, protocol);
        props.put(MAIL_SMTP_PORT, port);
        props.put(MAIL_SMTP_HOST, host);
        props.put(MAIL_SMTP_SSL_ENABLE, true);

//      props.put(MAIL_SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_PORT, String.valueOf(port) );
//      props.put(MAIL_SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_CLASS, socketFactoryClass);       
    }

public void sendPasswordToEmail (String recipientEmail, User user) throws Exception {
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail));         
        message.setSubject("Forgot Password Request");

        StringBuffer messageBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        messageBuffer.append("<html><h3>My Web App Portal</h3>");        
        messageBuffer.append("Here's your login details: <br><br>");
        messageBuffer.append("<b>Username:</b> "+user.getLoginUser()+"<br>");
        messageBuffer.append("<b>Password:</b> "+user.getPassword()+"<br><br> </html>");
        message.setContent(messageBuffer.toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, userName, passWord);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

    }catch(AuthenticationFailedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Everything I have seen says that you need a GoDaddy account in order to send email via GoDaddy.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes. I already have GoDaddy account. Thanks.

Comment: Wait. Is GoDaddy email account different to GoDaddy itself? Im really sorry.

Comment: I think you need GoDaddy email relays.  I think you get some if you have a domain, and you can pay for more.  But you should really be asking GoDaddy Support these questions!!

Answer (score 2):

My configuration in SpringBoot (replace domainname.com to your domainname and password)

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtpout.secureserver.net
    port: 465
    username: info@domainname.com
    password: password
    protocol: smtp
    properties.mail.smtp:
      auth: true
      ssl.enable: true
      ssl.trust: "*"
```

And I had to add `mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("info@domainname.com");` before sending the mail (else it was taking my system name and gave an error) and this setup worked.